# Swagger annotation traversing all tables in DB

Tags: java, swagger, jax-rs

I'm having a look at a Java application that provides a REST API to access a database. Besides JAX-RS, it uses Swagger for generating the documentation and the testing website. On one of the routes, I've realized that the result example given by Swagger is extremely long (more than 140000) lines:

[image: Swagger problem]

This route is defined with the following code:

```
@GET
@Path("/getUsers")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Operation(
        summary = "Get available users",
        responses = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = OauthClientDetailsEntity.class)), description = "Get users list"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class)), description = "Error: Unauthorized"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Error: Internal Server Error")
        }
)
public Response getUsers() {
  // ....
}
```

The "trouble-maker" is the `idCliente` field, which is defined like this in the entity class:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "idCliente", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
private Cliente idCliente;
```

The table `Cliente` (customer in English) is related to a lot of tables in the DB, so I think that the problem is that Swagger is traversing all this tables, so the example result is so long. The class has more than 40 fields, and it looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
@XmlRootElement
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idCliente")
    private List<FacturaCliente> facturaClienteList;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idCliente")
    private List<OauthClientDetailsEntity> oauthClientDetailsEntityList;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cliente")
    private List<OauthAccessTokenEntity> oauthAccessTokenEntityList;

    @Column(name = "codigoPlantillaFacturacion")
    private String codigoPlantillaFacturacion;
    // etc...
}
```

I'm new to Swagger, so I'm not sure about how to deal with this problem. Is there any way to make Swagger not traverse all the related tables? Or, what other approach would be more efficient?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What does the User class look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore this field with [@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html#hidden())
 but you have to be aware that all that content will be rendered anyway. If you don't need this field better approach will be not to render it (e.g. `@JsonIgnore` annotation). The best option is to return DTO only with necessary fields instead of whole entity with its hierarchy.

Comment: Hi! I'll opt for the latest suggestion. I'll create a DTO class with only the required fields, although I'll have to do it all across the API... Thanks!